# Any way to optimize function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so, I have this function here

```
const [shopItems,setShopItems] = useState("");_
 useEffect(()=> {
    commerce.products.list().then((product) => {
      setShopItems(product)
    });
  }, [])

  
  function categorize(category) {
    let categoryarray = []
    if (shopItems!= "s") {
      shopItems.data.forEach((el)=> {
        for (let i =0; i < el.categories.length; i++) {
          if (el.categories[i].slug == category) categoryarray.push(el)
        }
      })

    }
    return categoryarray;
  }
```

the useEffect Hook was just for context, I'm mostly concerned about the categorize function. Is there anyway to optimize this since I have observed that my website scrolls very slowly, and I think this might be one of the culprits behind the slow scrolling speeds. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see to optimise that code is to exit as soon as a match is found. (I prefer using a `while` loop for this purpose).

```js
shopItems.data.forEach(el => {
    let idx = 0;
    while (idx < el.categories.length) {
        if (el.categories[idx].slug == category) {
            categoryarray.push(el);
            break;
        } else {
            idx++;
        }
    }
});
```

If you wanted something that looked slightly better (not mixing `forEach` and `for`, for example) you could use this: (no performance enhancements as far as I can see though)

```js
shopItems.data.forEach(el => {
    if (el.categories.map(({ slug }) => slug).includes(category)) categoryarray.push(el);
});
```

Or even use `reduce`:

```js
let categoryarray = shopItems.data.reduce((a, c) => {
    if (c.categories.map(({ slug }) => slug).includes(category) return a.concat(c);
    else return a;
}, []);
```

The first option is still the most performant as realistically it will run through the loop less times.

Comment: `not a for loop, so that you can exit` --> You can perfectly exit a `for` loop with `break`. You can even skip an iteration with `continue`, which is difficult to do with `while`.

Comment: @JeremyThille I know but it's better IMO to use a while loop so that it's clear the condition controlling the loop is not purely counted.

Comment: This might be more performant in js but this will not help when we are talking about react. The problem is not that the for loop itself is costly, its that it is costly and runs every render.

Comment: @JackBashford thanks. It didn't really make a noticeable change, but I guess its due to my own project architecture. Still more efficient than my method though

Answer (score 1):

You can use useMemo
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

useMemo works by having 2 parameters. A function and an array of dependencies, if any of the dependencies change it re-runs the provided function and stores the value, next render if the dependencies havent changed it just uses the previous value.

```
const categories = useMemo(() =>  
    let categoryarray = []
    if (shopItems!= "s") {
      shopItems.data.forEach((el)=> {
        for (let i =0; i < el.categories.length; i++) {
          if (el.categories[i].slug == category) categoryarray.push(el)
        }
      })

    }
    return categoryarray;
}, [shopItems.data, category])
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go read up on the docs for that one. looks like an interesting hook to try

Comment: sorry for bothering you again, but how exactly is use Memo different from useEffect with ([object]) as the second argument?

Comment: @KevinH useMemo returns an object you can then use in the rest of the render code. useEffect just runs some code.

You should use useMemo conservatively as it does take some performance toll, but when you need to do a heavy calculation on a component that renders a lot its great.

You could replace useMemo with useEffect that calls a setState of a useState, but its seems a little messier

Comment: oh that makes sense. Thanks